# Conditional monotone convergence theorem for general random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The problem is from [Sourav Chatterjee' lecture notes on probability](https://souravchatterjee.su.domains/stats310notes.pdf) exercise 9.2.10 and
described by the followings:

Given $X_1 \leq X_2 \leq... \to X $ and all of their expected value exist . If $\mathcal{G}$ is a
sub $\sigma$-algebra , show

$E(X_n \rvert \mathcal{G}) \to E(X \rvert \mathcal{G})$   a.e on $\{E(X_1 \rvert \mathcal{G})< \infty\}$

The hint suggest us to consider the truncation $A_k=\{E(X_1 \rvert \mathcal{G})<1\}$ and $X_n 1_{A_k}$ .
My idea is to let $Y_n^{(k)} = X_n 1_{A_k}$ , $Y^{(k)}= X 1_{A_k}$
and try to show $E(Y_n^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G}) \to E(Y^{(k)})$ using the fact that
$E(Y_n^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G})+k \geq 0$ and conditional MCT for nonegative random variables
. Here is my question :

(1) How to show $E(Y_n^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G})$  is monotone increasing ? Here we don't assume
that random variables are $\mathcal{L}^1$ , $Y^{(k)}-Y_n^{(k)}$ may be $\infty - \infty$ . Even if the subtraction exists , it's not enough to ensure the linearity , i.e
$E(Y^{(k)}-Y_n^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G}) = E(Y^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G})-E(Y_n^{(k)} \rvert \mathcal{G})$

(2) Even (1) is solved , I still have no idea how to apply nonegative conditional MCT . Need some hint here . Or maybe the  direction of my proof is wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: How is $E(X|\mathcal G)$ is defined when you don't know whether $X \geq 0$ or $E|X|<\infty$?

Comment: Actually I have same question as you at first . So I just presume that conditional expectations exist otherwise the problem is even unsolveable

Answer (score 0):

Its not so hard to show it as far as $\operatorname{E}[X_1]$ and $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists (I'm assuming here that by "exists" it means that they are finite), just set $Y_n:=X-X_n$, then $Y_n\geqslant 0$ and $Y_n\downarrow 0$ almost sure, moreover $\operatorname{E}[Y_1]<\infty $ so applying the monotone convergence theorem you get that $\operatorname{E}[Y_n|\mathcal{G}]\to 0$ almost sure, but this just means that $\operatorname{E}[X_n|\mathcal{G}]\to \operatorname{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$ a.s. ∎

Comment: I understand your point . But this problem will become trivial  under $\mathcal{L}^1$ assumption since we can directly apply conditional LDCT